# Adding words to links generated by hyperref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, pdf, cleveref

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{polski}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
.
\caption{A figure}
\label{fff}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]

Rysunek~\ref{fff} jest zabawny, bo na rysunku~\ref{fff} nic nie ma.
\end{document}
```

In this sample, a clickable link is added to output PDF for `1` and `1`. I want to be able to change them to `Rysunek 1` and `rysunku 1`. I want to be able to put any other text + number of the figure into a hyperlink.
The word `rysunek` can't be set in preamble as a default because there is a declension in Polish.
The same question goes for tables, listings, equations, pages (`pageref`) etc (basically any reference).

HTML equivalent of my MWE:

```html
Rysunek <href="fff">1</a> jest zabawny, bo na rysunku <a href="fff">1</a> nic nie ma.
```

I want it to be:

```html
<href="fff">Rysunek 1</a> jest zabawny, bo na <a href="fff">rysunku 1</a> nic nie ma.
```

Comment: Try to use `\autoref` instead of `\ref`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The explanation of `\labelcref` in the documentation of `cleveref` is not very clear, but it seems to produce only the label, without any attached string.

A possibility would be to say

```
\crefformat{figure}{#2\templabel~#1#3}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\casecref}[2]{%
  \begingroup\def\templabel{#1}\cref{#2}\endgroup}
```

so that the output of

```
\casecref{Rysunek}{fff} jest zabawny, bo na
\casecref{rysunku}{fff} nic nie ma.
```

would be what you're expecting. I'm afraid you have to set `\crefformat` in a similar way for all the reference types you're going to use.

Comment: "I'm afraid you have to set `\crefformat` in a similar way for all the reference types you're going to use."
That's not a problem :).

Comment: @egreg: With your proposed code, a user would *always* have to use `\casecref` and couldn't use `\cref` directly any longer, right?

Comment: @Mico Only for the types redeclared with `\crefformat` in the proposed way. However, for languages with declension it's difficult to find a better way: usually there are different terminations for the same cases. A different way might be to memorize all the declension for the required word and add a key for the case to use.

Answer (score 14):

Macro `\hyperref` also knows an optional argument. Then it expects a label name
and the only mandatory argument contains the text:

```
\hyperref[labelname]{text made to link}
```

Because we have now a link, we do not need another link inside causing
by `\ref` to the same location. Therefore `\ref` (and also `\pageref`)
have a star form if `hyperref` is used. With star the references
are set without link.

Applied to the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{polski}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
.
\caption{A figure}
\label{fff}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]

\hyperref[fff]{Rysunek~\ref*{fff}} jest zabawny,
bo na \hyperref[fff]{rysunku~\ref*{fff}} nic nie ma.
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Your suggestion works superb....Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 10):

Your best option may be to use the [cleveref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/) package. To include the "name" of the item being cross-referenced in the hyperlink target, you'll need to load it with the `nameinlink` option:

```
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
```

Remember that it's necessary to load the `cleveref` package *after* the `hyperref` package (and any other packages that manipulate the `\label` macro). With this package loaded, and supposing you have two equations labelled, say, `{eq:a}` and `{eq:b}`, you would cross-refernce the first one by issuing the command `\cref{eq:a}`, or both at once with the command `\cref{eq:a,eq:b}`.

However, the fact that language of your documents would appear to be Polish raises (at least) two complications.

- First, the default language the `cleveref` package employs for cross-referenced items ("equation", "figure", "table", "page", etc) is English. Currently, the package includes options to use about a dozen other languages to typeset the names of cross-referenced items, but Polish is not (yet) one of them. Aside: If you contacted Toby Cubitt (the author of the `cleveref` package) and sent him a list of item names in Polish, I'm sure he'd be delighted to set up a new, Polish, language option. (The items include: equation, figure, subfigure, table, subtable, page, part, chapter, section, appendix, enumi, footnote, theorem, lemma, corollary, proposition, definition, result, example, remark, note, algorithm, listing, and line!)

  In the meantime, though, you'll have to use some of the low-level controls of the cleveref package to supply all the names (in nominative singular and nominative plural forms) yourself. E.g., in the preamble after loading the package, you'd have to enter commands of the form (using English just for this example)

  ```
  \crefname{equation}{equation}{equations}  %substitute Polish equivalents here...
  \Crefname{equation}{Equation}{Equations} 
  \crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures}
  \Crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures}
  ```

  and so on.
- Second, Polish is a language that declines nouns, i.e., the nominative, genetive, etc forms are generally different, right? The user guide for the `cleveref` has this to say for use of the cleveref package with such languages:

> Note that if you're writing in a language in which nouns decline, the `\cref` and `\cpageref` commands may be less useful, as they always produce the cross-reference name
>   in the nominative case. In such languages, you may instead prefer to use the
>   `\labelcref` and `\labelcpageref` commands. Unlike `\cref` and `\cpageref`, these
>   don't produce the name in front of the cross-reference, so you must supply it (in
>   the appropriate case) yourself. But they do still cope with multi-references, so you
>   still gain some benefit from using `cleveref`.

In short, be prepared to use the `\labelcref` command at times and supply the associated noun's name yourself in the appropriate (non-nominative) case. Or, rephrase your sentences that contain cross-references so that they only use the nominative cases.

Addendum: To use `\labelcref` instead of `\cref`, you would type `of Figures~\labelcref{fig:a,fig:b}` instead of `of \cref{fig:a,fig:b}`. A side-effect of this construction is that the noun (here, `Figures`) that precedes the `\labelcref` command will *not* be part of the hyperlink even if the `nameinlink` option was set.

Comment: What is `\labelcref` syntax? i'm unable to find it in `http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf`.

Comment: Ummm, I find instances of `\labelcref` on pages 4, 7, 17, etc of that document... Anyway, `\labelcref` acts exactly like `\cref` except that it doesn't prefix the name of the cross-referenced item (or items) to the label(s).

Comment: Yes, `\labelcref` is mentioned on those pages, but I'm still unable to find information how to use this. Should I put `\labelcref{fff}`? I don't think so. Where should I put my `rysunek` word to get [HTML equivalent] `<a href="fff">rysunek 1</a>`? I can only get `rysunek <a href="fff">1</a>` (posted in question)

Comment: @Ichibann: please see the addendum to my answer.

Comment: Mico, you said: "A side-effect of this construction is that the noun [...] will not be part of the hyperlink even if the nameinlink option was set." So what's the point? In my MWE I already have a noun which is not part of a hyperlink... The point of my question is to put this noun into a hyperlink.

Comment: @Ichibann: "So what's the point?" Well, as long as you can phrase your sentences in a way such that the cross-referenced nouns will appear in nominative (singular or plural) form, you can use `\cref` without any issues, right? Furthermore, the `cleveref` package does lots of neat things, in addition to prefixing nouns to labels, that are worthwhile using even if the language you write in forces you to use `\labelcref` rather than `\cref`. But, as I stated clearly in the very first sentence of my answer, the `cleveref` package *may be* -- but not necessarily *is* -- your best option.

Comment: @Mico I have a bit relevant question; how can I make the whole cross-reference (label and number) a clickable link not just the number?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou - You would need to specify the option `nameinlink` while loading `cleveref`.

Answer (score 5):

You should look at the cleveref package :
http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/help/Catalogue/entries/cleveref.html

It determines automatically the type of a cross reference. Thus

```
\ref{apicture}
```

will give : Figure N instead of just the number of the figure.

EDIT : an other possibility which is less automatic is the use of `fncylab` package. Here is an example which define the behavior of the `\ref` command for floats : figure, table, equation and codesource (a custum float previously defined).

```
\usepackage{fncylab}
\labelformat{figure}{\sffamily \figurename~#1}
\labelformat{table}{\tablename~#1}
\labelformat{equation}{\sffamily équation~#1}
\labelformat{codesource}{\sffamily code source~#1}
```

If I well understand this do what you want, hereafter is an output example where you can see that the link include `eqution 4.6` :
[image]

Comment: Ok, but I want to put any text into a hyperlink.

Comment: hyperref package : `\href{http://www.alink.org}{a name}`. Is it specific to crossreference or not ? I edit my answer with `fncylab`  possibilities.

Comment: Yes, that is much better but still not what I want. For example I might want to put into figure's label `Rysunek` and another time `rysunku` (due to declension) or another time `ungabunga` just because I could. Is that possible?

Comment: I do not understand anythink about your language :) but nevertheless, a trick could be to define differents float environment. For example, one for Rysunek and one for ungabunga. For the declension (pluriel I guess ?) I do not have idea. When I used fncylab, I wrote for example Rysunek 1 and Rysunek 2 ...

Comment: Why define anything for every environment? I just want to wrote something like: `Na \newref{rysunku}{fig:fff} jest ładnie`. Declension is not just plural, BTW. In Polish (and many other languages) form of a noun depends on grammatical case. For example "rysunek" (the figure) is Nominative case and "[na] rysunku" is Locative case ([on] this figure).