# how can I link "fig. 1" rather than "1"?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

If I use `\ref{fig:fig1}` command, It only makes hyperlink to word "1"

Or `\autoref{fig:fig1}` , it write Figure 1, but link exists on only word "1" also.

As an other way, `\cref{fig:fig1}` write "fig. 1", but link exists on only word "1".

However, I want to make it to, word "fig. 1" is written, and the hyperlink to figure 1 exists on word "fig. 1" not only on "1"

How can I do that?

Comment: Package `\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}` and `\cref{fig:fig1}`

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60787/117534